# Trying to Import WSDL in Mule ESB, Error as mentioned in image

Tags: parsing, jaxb, mule, esb, xsom

When trying to import the WSDL in CXF block in Mule ESB am facing below parsing error. Please can someone help.

[image]

Comment: Please post your wsdl. Looks like some error in the wsdl.

Comment: apologies for the late response. Well the WSDL is custom obtained from Oracle OMS tool. I do not have permission to post the same. If any specific section in particular i can share?

Comment: Okay, the line 56 which gives error on the screen? Are there any duplicate fields called "Value"?